# Is it possible in Cloud Foundry Application to download a Jar--File in manifest file?

Tags: java, jar, cloud-foundry

Is it possible to not upload a jar file from local disk, but downloading a jar-file inside cloud foundry container? i know its possible with docker images but im looking for a other way using the java buildpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with standard buildpacks (e.g., [Java buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack)).

If you want such functionality, you would need to [create your own buildpack](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/custom.html).

Comment: This is the same for other apps as it is for Java.  With Cloud Foundry, you *push* code.  If you want to trigger behaviors off of check-in's to source control or completion of builds, you should set up a CI/CD pipeline where the last step is a `cf push` to Cloud Foundry.